Order in which instructions are printed/executed
Why the output is in diffrent order than it is declared?
Shouldnt the output be in this order?
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
Instead it is:

I assume the issue is in assigning "bbb" value to the text variable, but i dont know why is that and how to do this the correct way.
Instructions:
    section .data
text db "aaaa", 10
text2 db "cccc", 10

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, text
    call _printstring
   
    mov rax, "bbb"
    mov [text], rax
   
mov rax, text
    call _printstring

mov rax, text2
call _printstring

    mov eax, 60
    xor edi, edi
    syscall

_printstring:
push rax
mov rbx, 0
_printstringloop:
inc rax
inc rbx
mov cl, [rax]
cmp cl, 0
jne _printstringloop

mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
pop rsi
mov rdx, rbx
syscall

ret


To add to the answer, labels don't terminate strings or pretty much anything else, so, text2 refers to a sub string of text, that starts with the cs , while text refers to a longer string that includes the cs.  You can put a label pretty much wherever you want and it simply provide the assembly program with an address of what's on the next line, without necessarily affecting anything that came before.

Note that while that is true for data labels, it is also similarly true for code labels: code labels do not end sections of code, they do not alter flow of control.  Control flow usually involves a branch instruction referring to a label, but the label itself does virtually nothing — code labels don't execute or separate code and neither do data labels create data or separate data.


Shouldnt the output be in this order?


aaaa bbbb cccc

Not with this code.
What happens here is that this string is printed first: "aaaa\ncccc\n"
_printstring does not stop at the newline, it goes all the way to the zero terminator, which wasn't explicit in the strings but there is apparently some zero-fill after the data, as usual, but in general you may not want to rely on that.
Then:

mov rax, "bbb"
mov [text], rax


So after that, "bbb" (no newline) is printed, as observed. This also nukes the contents of text2, since it's an 8 byte store and the last 3 of those 8 bytes are the first 3 bytes of text2, and those bytes are zero so printing text2 doesn't result in any printable text (presumably a zero character is printed, but it's invisible)
